# How to get Google search card html

Tags: html, search, web, meta

Many websites show a card when you do a Google search, for example here is one for twitter:

[image: Google search card for twitter]

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about these cards and how to implement them.

My questions are as follows:

(1) What is that correct name for these 'Google search cards'?

(2) How can I create a card for my website? Is it using html meta tags? or is this data scraped from wikipedia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer searching around google's webmaster tools. The proper name for the 'card' is called google 'Knowledge Panel'. More info here: [Specify your social profiles to Google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles#include_your_social_profile_in_search_results)